# Why won't top padding apply to my anchor?

Tags: css

I have an anchor inside a div inside another div. For some reason, top padding won't apply to it, but bottom and side padding will. Anybody know why?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.box a {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 60px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <a>Test</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't work because by default `a` is an inline element. If you want to treat it like a block one, you should make it block or inline-block (recommended in this case):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.box a {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 60px 15px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <a>Test</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Being an inline element, `a` is rendered on content baseline. But even though padding-top/bottom values are applied (unlike margin-top/bottom which are ignored by inline elements), increased padding causes change of height of the element. However despite of the height (which is also ignored) inline element is still rendered on a baseline, that's why changing padding-top/bottom doesn't shift the element visually.

Comment: Upvoted because it answers the question asked, and gives a solution. EDIT: Plus I was busy typing out the inline-block solution myself...

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.box a {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <a>Test</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add line-height. code updated above

Answer (score 0):

You could try put the anchor around a div with padding. This probably isn't an elegant solution.